# Convert statement for use as module

Tags: node.js, express

In node I have added `"type": "module",` to my package.json file to convert to ES modules.

In my main server file I have the following:

```
readdirSync("./routes").map((route) => app.use("/api", require(`./routes/${route}`)));
```

It uses the file system to dynamically map file names to Express for use in the middleware (to avoid having to `import...from` for every file).

For example ./route/auth.js contains this code:

```
import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
    console.log("register endpoint -> ", req.body);

});

// module.exports = router;
export default router;
```

How do I modify that preceding statement to work without require()? I understand how to do it for one liner imports, but I obviously can't use `import...from` here.

Answer (score 0):

```
readdirSync("./routes").map(async (route) => app.use("/api", await import(`./routes/${route}`)));
```

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Module at Function.use". In that file I converted from 'module.exports = router' to 'export default router'. Perhaps it needs another change?

Comment: also in the stack trace: "throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))"

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.